# docs.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i'm working with my project using react native and firestore, i'm trying to get document from my collection 'requests' by uid that have the same uid with current logged in user and after retrieve it show the data but i got an error `TypeError: docs.forEach is not a function`. Previously i have successfully add the document to collection with current logged in user uid. Here is my code

```js
constructor() {
    this.state={
      requests:[]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchRequests();
  }
  
  fetchRequests(){
    this.subscriber = firebase.firestore()
    .collection("requests").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).onSnapshot(docs => {
      let requests = []
      docs.forEach(doc => {
        requests.push(doc.data())
      })
      this.setState({requests})
  })
}

buildPanels() { 
  if (this.state.requests.length !== 0) {
    return this.state.requests.map((req, idx) => {
        return <View key={idx} style={styles.panel}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={styles.panelRow}>
              <Text style={styles.panelText}>Name</Text>
              <Text style={styles.panelText}>{req.name}</Text>  
            </View>
            <View style={styles.panelRow}>
              <Text style={styles.panelText}>Blood Type</Text>
              <Text style={{flex: 0.5}}>{req.golDarah}</Text>  
            </View>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.deleteData}>
                      <Text style={{color:color.red}}>End Request</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
      });
  }
  else{
    return <View>
      <Text style={{fontSize: fontSize.regular + 1, color: color.red}}>you dont have request</Text>
    </View>
  }     
}

render(){
  return(
    {this.buildPanels()} 
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you select firebase.firestore.collection('your collection').get() you're allowed use forEach because you will loop documents. Your question you get a 'Specific Document' so you don't have document to loop.

In your case

```
firestore()
  .collection("requests")
  .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
  .get()
  .then(docs => {
    if (docs.exists) {
      console.log('requests data: ', docs.data());
    }
  });
```